# Webinar Ignition Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, ignition, webinar

`define('WI_WEBINAR_DATA_POST', true );`

By using this function, I store webinars separately, but now, I'm unable to edit it with elementor.

I'm unable to edit the separately stored webinars, and I can't find any page editor settings. Also, can't access the page.